# Makefile ld: library not found for -llibsfml-graphics

Tags: c++, makefile, sfml, lib

## Problem

Makefile doesn't appear to be able to locate compiled lib file, on local machine !?

Attempting to link "/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1_1/lib/llibsfml-graphics.2.5.1.dylib" library, however, linker is not able to locate !?

[image]

## Code

### Makefile

```makefile
## Binary
BIN := Entity-Simulation

## Compiler
CXX := g++
CXX_FLAGS := -std=c++11

## Directories
SRC_DIRS := ./include

## Linker
LD_FLAG := -L/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1_1/lib
LIBS := -lsfml-graphics.2.5.1

# Files
SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name '*.hpp')

OBJS := $(patsubst %.hpp, %.o, $(SRCS))

# COMMANDS
## All
all: $(BIN)

## Binary
$(BIN): $(OBJS) main.cpp
    touch $@
    $(CXX) $(LD_FLAG) $(CXX_FLAGS) main.cpp $(OBJS) -o $@ $(LIBS)

## Objects
%.o: %.hpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXX_FLAGS) $< -o $@

## Clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS)
    rm -f $(BIN)
```

## Output

```bash
g++ -c -std=c++11 include/headers.hpp -o include/headers.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 include/config.hpp -o include/config.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 include/simulation/simulation.hpp -o include/simulation/simulation.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 include/utilities/renderer/SFML_utilities.hpp -o include/utilities/renderer/SFML_utilities.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 include/utilities/specific/step_colors.hpp -o include/utilities/specific/step_colors.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 include/utilities/general/uniform_grid.hpp -o include/utilities/general/uniform_grid.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 include/utilities/general/scale.hpp -o include/utilities/general/scale.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 include/utilities/general/RNG.hpp -o include/utilities/general/RNG.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 include/utilities/general/display.hpp -o include/utilities/general/display.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 include/common/math/math.hpp -o include/common/math/math.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 include/common/structs/general/angle.hpp -o include/common/structs/general/angle.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 include/common/structs/general/point.hpp -o include/common/structs/general/point.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 include/common/structs/general/matrix.hpp -o include/common/structs/general/matrix.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 include/common/structs/general/cell.hpp -o include/common/structs/general/cell.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 include/common/structs/general/color.hpp -o include/common/structs/general/color.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 include/common/structs/custom/attributes.hpp -o include/common/structs/custom/attributes.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 include/common/structs/custom/entity.hpp -o include/common/structs/custom/entity.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 include/common/static/colors.hpp -o include/common/static/colors.o
g++ -c -std=c++11 include/common/static/states.hpp -o include/common/static/states.o

touch Entity-Simulation

g++ -L/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1_1/lib -std=c++11 main.cpp  ./include/headers.o  ./include/config.o  ./include/simulation/simulation.o  ./include/utilities/renderer/SFML_utilities.o  ./include/utilities/specific/step_colors.o  ./include/utilities/general/uniform_grid.o  ./include/utilities/general/scale.o  ./include/utilities/general/RNG.o  ./include/utilities/general/display.o  ./include/common/math/math.o  ./include/common/structs/general/angle.o  ./include/common/structs/general/point.o  ./include/common/structs/general/matrix.o  ./include/common/structs/general/cell.o  ./include/common/structs/general/color.o  ./include/common/structs/custom/attributes.o  ./include/common/structs/custom/entity.o  ./include/common/static/colors.o  ./include/common/static/states.o -o Entity-Simulation -llibsfml-graphics.2.5.1 -v

Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)

Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.5.0

Thread model: posix

InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx11.0.0 -Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_ -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=all -fno-strict-return -fno-rounding-math -munwind-tables -target-sdk-version=12.1 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden-static-local-var -target-cpu penryn -tune-cpu generic -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 711 -v -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include -stdlib=libc++ -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -Wno-reorder-init-list -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-c99-designator -Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class -Wno-extra-semi-stmt -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-enum-float-conversion -Wno-elaborated-enum-base -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir "/Users/justinbyrne/Programs/Xcode/Entity Simulation/Entity Simulation" -ferror-limit 19 -stack-protector 1 -fstack-check -mdarwin-stkchk-strong-link -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fno-cxx-modules -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fcommon -fcolor-diagnostics -clang-vendor-feature=+nullptrToBoolConversion -clang-vendor-feature=+messageToSelfInClassMethodIdReturnType -clang-vendor-feature=+disableInferNewAvailabilityFromInit -clang-vendor-feature=+disableNeonImmediateRangeCheck -clang-vendor-feature=+disableNonDependentMemberExprInCurrentInstantiation -fno-odr-hash-protocols -clang-vendor-feature=+revert09abecef7bbf -mllvm -disable-aligned-alloc-awareness=1 -mllvm -enable-dse-memoryssa=0 -o /var/folders/py/12nv2qy16qn9sgdw6d75bgg00000gn/T/main-c59e7a.o -x c++ main.cpp

clang -cc1 version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30) default target x86_64-apple-darwin20.5.0

ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/Library/Frameworks"

#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)

End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch x86_64 -platform_version macos 11.0.0 12.1 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -o Entity-Simulation -L/usr/local/Cellar/sfml/2.5.1_1/lib -L/usr/local/lib /var/folders/py/12nv2qy16qn9sgdw6d75bgg00000gn/T/main-c59e7a.o ./include/headers.o ./include/config.o ./include/simulation/simulation.o ./include/utilities/renderer/SFML_utilities.o ./include/utilities/specific/step_colors.o ./include/utilities/general/uniform_grid.o ./include/utilities/general/scale.o ./include/utilities/general/RNG.o ./include/utilities/general/display.o ./include/common/math/math.o ./include/common/structs/general/angle.o ./include/common/structs/general/point.o ./include/common/structs/general/matrix.o ./include/common/structs/general/cell.o ./include/common/structs/general/color.o ./include/common/structs/custom/attributes.o ./include/common/structs/custom/entity.o ./include/common/static/colors.o ./include/common/static/states.o -llibsfml-graphics.2.5.1 -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a

ld: library not found for -llibsfml-graphics.2.5.1
```

## Goal

Try to understand how to (either) link to a pre-compiled *.dylib file, or create my own with the lib *.hpp files, and then link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to include `-lsfml-system.2.5.1` and `-lsfml-window.2.5.1` to my `LIBS` variable... meow everything compiles correctly.

Changed:

`LIBS := -lsfml-graphics.2.5.1`

to

`LIBS := -lsfml-graphics.2.5.1 -lsfml-system.2.5.1 -lsfml-window.2.5.1`

Many thanks !

Comment: I'm pretty sure there must have been some additional changes than just the one in this answer. The inability of a linker to find a library is a different problem to some missing symbols, which would be the only benefit of specifying additional libs rather than changing the search list.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

On systems where you use `libX.a` (or `libX.so`, or `libX.dylib` like on macOS) libraries, the name of the library is `X`.

You should not include the `lib` prefix or the suffix (`.a` or `.so` or `.dylib`). Those are added by the linker automatically when searching for the library.

The name of the `sfml-graphics.2.5.1` library is just that, and it's the name you should use: `-lsfml-graphics.2.5.1`

Comment: I removed the "lib" prefix within the "LIBS" variable... equating to `LIBS := -lsfml-graphics.2.5.1` ... and the now I get: `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`. There's no reference to the .dylib suffix || extension... therefore, no need to eliminate that portion. - Will update this post in accordance. –